# How to make an element in a list nested within a list have a default value?

Tags: list-manipulation, scripting

I would like to be able to skip the necessity of entering the last element in the nested lists, and get some default value instead if they are not entered.

Below are two lines of code. The first line shows what i have to do now to ake my function perform propely, and the second line shows what I wish to be able to do instead:

[image: The two lines of code]

`allstarz[{{{-2, -2}, 1, 3}, {{-2, -5}, 2, 7}, {{1, 5}, 3,  9}, {{7, -7}, 4, 11}, {{9, 9}, 5, 13}}]`

`allstarz[{{{-2, -2}, 1}, {{-2, -5}, 2, 7}, {{1, 5}, 3, 9}, {{7, -7},  4, 11}, {{9, 9}, 5, 13}}]`

Comment: Edit your question to include the actual code (`InputForm`) in a code block rather than an image of the code.

Comment: does the default behavior only apply to the first member of the list or does it need to work for any member of the list. I see that the elements in your first example are all of the same "shape", which suggests that something that works for one might be expected to work for all.

Comment: Is there some pattern to these values? The third sub-elements form a simple sequence, and the 4th sub-elements almost form a sequence of odd numbers. Maybe you can be even more ambitious than just one default value. If we knew the semantics, maybe we could do more.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer.

The defualt behaviour should be able to be applied to all members of the list.

Comment: okay great! so, what is the default behavior?

Comment: Based on the way the original question was asked, it sounds like you want to use the built-in functionality for specifying default values in function definitions, which typically involves special patterns. Given the shape of your input, I think that approach would be complicated, messy, and unreliable. So, I'm thinking that a better approach would be to simply apply a "clean-up" function to the input. So, knowing what the default behavior actually is would make this easier to answer.

Comment: The default value should just be a number, for example "5", there is no behavior :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that all elements should have a length of 4. If not, the defualt value is appended:

```
fix[dat_, def_ : 5] := If[Length[#] == 3, #, Append[#, def]] & /@ dat;
```

To test with the given default value:

```
dat = {{{-2, -2}, 1}, {{-2, -5}, 2, 7}, {{1, 5}, 3, 9}, {{7, -7}, 4, 
    11}, {{9, 9}, 5, 13}};
fix[dat]
(* {{{-2, -2}, 1, 5}, {{-2, -5}, 2, 7}, {{1, 5}, 3, 9}, {{7, -7}, 4, 
  11}, {{9, 9}, 5, 13}} *)
```

and with a different default value of 10:

```
fix[dat, 10]
(* {{{-2, -2}, 1, 10}, {{-2, -5}, 2, 7}, {{1, 5}, 3, 9}, {{7, -7}, 4, 
  11}, {{9, 9}, 5, 13}} *)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, this is what I was looking for <3

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I suspect this is actually not what you want, but it'll be easier to discuss with a concrete example. Let's start with a function that'll clean up malformed data:

```
fixArgument[arg : {{_, _}, _}] := Append[arg, 5];
fixArgument[arg_] := arg
```

Writing it this way will allow you to extend it to other types of "fixes", like, say you have a way to fix the first element if it's a single element list instead of a pair, then you can add a rule for that.

Anyway, now you can clean your arguments for use in your other function:

```
allstarz[args_List] :=
  With[
    {cleanArgs = fixArgument /@ args},
    <...do stuff here with cleanArgs...>]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it

```
dat = {{{-2, -2}, 1}, {{-2, -5}, 2, 7}, {{1, 5}, 3, 9}, {{7, -7}, 4, 
    11}, {{9, 9}, 5, 13}};
sltn[xx_] := 
 With[{def = xx}, dat /. {{i_, j_}, k_} :> {{i, j}, k, def}]
```

Let's do the value `xx=5` to compare with @Daniel Huber

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[Flatten@(fix[dat] - sltn[5])]
```

> [image: true]

In the above, I have used

```
fix[dat_, def_ : 5] := If[Length[#] == 3, #, Append[#, def]] & /@ dat;
```

as proposed by [**`Daniel`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278073/how-to-make-an-element-in-a-list-nested-within-a-list-have-a-default-value/278081#278081).